# Sink water won't get hot unless shower is on

Tags: hot-water, bathroom-fixtures

The sink tap takes 20+ minutes to even get lukewarm, never hot. I have lived with this for a while until I made an interesting discovery the other day. When the shower (in the same bathroom) was running hot water, the sink water was warm! A miracle or wonky piping?

The offending faucet has separate hot/cold handles. The shower has separate hot/cold handles. The source is a tanked water heater (gas). No other shower or sink in the house has issues warming up quickly.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked to see if you have a hot water valve under the sink that is mostly shut off?

Comment: When you have hot water in the sink while your shower is running, is the cold water in your sink still cold even with the hot water turned off to the sink, or is it hot?

Comment: does the shower takers a few mins to warm up as well?